# How can you make secondary Y Axis in winform chart scrolllable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, scroll

I managed to make primary Y scroll
Any way to apply the configuration on the secondary Y?

```
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
```

This does not seem to work:

```
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY2.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY2.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
```

[image]

Comment: I might got you wrong ... that table has two dimensions, so it has one Y axis. What do you mean whith 'secondary Y axis? A second scroll bar indicator on the right side of your table?

Comment: It has two Y axis, look in the image in Red.
When I scroll down it scrolls only on the primary.